# How to display fetch data from MySQL Database as an output in rasa chatbot assistant?

Tags: python, sql, mysql, rasa, rasa-nlu

I am working on a project and I wanted to know how can I retrieve all the columns related to MySQL product_id when one of the id is entered to chatbot input field?

Comment: Please add a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to achieve, the relevant DDL An example with a small sample of data and the expected result would help explain

Answer (score 0):

Use the code  SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE product_id = 'productId'; which can be used to get the all the information from table with the productid specified.